# Use regex on htmlParseTree in R

Tags: html, r, regex, document

I have an HTML internal doc that I want to strip character vectors from.  Specifically, I am trying to parse Google results.

```
##create search query
  vcSearchInput <- "Alberta+Alabama+USA+latitude+longitude"

  ##scrape and parse google results to XML
  vcSearchOutput <- getURL(paste0("http://www.google.com/search?q=",vcSearchInput))
```

from here, I can that exactly what I want comes after:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?um=1&amp;ie=UTF-8&amp;fb=1&amp;gl=us&amp;sa=X&amp;ll=
```

I have figured out converting to character:

```
vaSearchOutput <- paste(capture.output(vaSearchOutput,file="test.txt"),collapse="")
```

But, of course, my search string has TONS of special characters that require escaping.

I tried:

```
gregexpr("http\\:\\/\\/maps\\.google\\.com\\/maps\\?um\\=1\\&amp\\;ie\\=UTF\\-8\\&amp\\;fb\\=1\\&amp\\;gl\\=us\\&amp\\;sa\\=X\\&amp\\;ll\\=",vaSearchOutput,ignore.case=T)
```

I tried:

```
regmatches(regexpr("maps\\.google\\.com.*",vaSearchOutput,ignore.case=T),vaSearchOutput)
```

and received:

```
Error in so + attr(m, "match.length")[ind] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

So how can I work with these kinds of variable types to find regular expressions?

Comment: What exactly did you pass to the regular expression function? Sounds like you passed the wrong thing. Show the code that actually produces the error.

Comment: Added my attempt to the question

Comment: It looks like you've edited out the question from your question now. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I am really just trying to learn how to work my way around an internal doc, generally.  I don't want to have to come back for all my specific questions.  Specifically, here, I want the latitude and longitude included in the URL.

Comment: If you are trying to parse an HTML document, I suggest looking that the `xml2` and `rvest` packages.  This should be more straight forward than using grep.